# MOOCs Python Programming exercise: Name and age

Tags: python

I am very new in coding, Python will be my first language. I am trying to figure this one out but I am stuck trying to understand what it is I am missing.

### Exercise

Please write a program which asks the user for their name and year of birth. The program then prints out a message as follows:

### Sample output

```
What is your name? Frances Fictitious
Which year were you born? 1990
Hi Frances Fictitious, you will be 31 years old at the end of the year 2021
```

### My code

```
name = input("What is your name?")
born = int(input("Which year were you born?")
year = (2021-born)
print(f"Hi " + name + "you will be {2021-year} years old at the end of the year 2021" )
```

### Error message

```
TypeError on line 3: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

I have removed 'year' completely, made input an int and change the 3rd line multiple times, nothing has worked. I've reverted back to the course and looked at other code examples online but I can't figure seem to figure out what it is i am doing wrong. the second type error msg i get is an invalid syntax

Comment: `int(input("Which year were you born?")` should give a SyntaxError, since it misses a closing parenthesis. Not a TypeError.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. This code doesn't raise that error, it raises a SyntaxError. Once you fix the typo, if you're still having difficulty, read [ask] and make a [mre]. See also [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing parenthesis and you also have an error in the print. Just try this, that should work:

```
name = input("What is your name?")
born = int(input("Which year were you born?"))
print(f"Hi {name}, you will be {2021-born} years old at the end of the year 2021")
```